# Audit requirements for a Safe{Wallet} app

Tags: safe-core

I am working on a Safe app and thus I am curious: what are the requirements for the smart contract audit?

Comment: Hi! I'd recommend editing your question to make it clearer: are you looking to have your app audited, and are asking how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply that it was externally audited by professional security researchers or a specialized firm such as Certik, Hedera, Consensys Dilligence etc., producing an independent report stating potential vulnerabilities found and how they were solved.

Hope it helps, Louis

Comment: Got it, thank you!!